# img not working despite everything coded properly

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I absolutely CANNOT figure out why my background image is not working. Any help to solve this would be GREATLY appreciated. In the CSS portion, you will find "Backg.jpg". For whatever reason, it refuses to show up even when put as a png, named differently, put in a different folder, or even put into the html (Background image for the body). It's currently structured into a folder called "img". If needed, I can provide screenshots to better show how the folders are. But I can near 95% guarantee folder structure isn't the issue unless i'm just missing something critical.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="socialmediaicons">
                    <img src="img/fb.png">
                    <img src="img/twitter.png">
                    <img src="img/g+.png">
                </div>
                <h1>COMPUTER</h1>
                <h3>Services for both home, and business</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel+Sans);

* {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Martel Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-image: url(img/backg.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#socialmediaicons {
    width: 12%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#socialmediaicons img {
    width: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#header {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#header h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

File structure can be found
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4tjC.png)

Comment: Can you post the folder structure of your project? Just the relevant bits, showing where your css files, html files and image files are located. My hunch is that you need to reference it like this `url(../img/backg.jpg);` because your img folder is probably not inside your css folder.

Comment: Edited with file structure. Capitalization is fine, both match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs in CSS files are relative to the CSS file that contains them.

In other words, the file you're trying to load from your CSS is:

```
/css/img/backg.jpg
```

Change the url to either be absolute (the FQDN and path) or navigate relative to the CSS file:

```
url( ../img/backg.jpg );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove **background-color** from **#wrapper**

```
#wrapper {
    /*background-color: #ffffff;*/Remove or comment this line
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel+Sans);

* {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Martel Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-in-geometric-style_1013-17.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
    /*background-color: #ffffff;*/
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#socialmediaicons {
    width: 12%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#socialmediaicons img {
    width: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#header {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#header h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="socialmediaicons">
                    <img src="img/fb.png">
                    <img src="img/twitter.png">
                    <img src="img/g+.png">
                </div>
                <h1>COMPUTER</h1>
                <h3>Services for both home, and business</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Went ahead and removed that line, along with all the others for the wrapper considering they did nothing, but alas it still does not work.

Comment: but you can see in the snippet its working @Warriorsfury .

Answer (score 0):

Could be a misspelling... try to add it manually in your `<div>` to see if it reads accordingly. ie: `<img src="img/back.jpg">` Because you'll get intellisense aid, that should be the right route to copy and paste in your CSS.
Another try.. just convert your png file to jpg.... maybe is inheriting transparency or white background which melt with your body css... Let me know if helps.

Comment: None of those worked sadly. I've attempted to switch to png as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both Matt and Moishe have a point, so first check filenames and positions.
After that you'll notice that it still won't work because of your wrapper id:

```
#wrapper
```

it has 100% width/height and it's overlaying over your body with position: fixed and top:0; left:0.

If you remove that wrapper you'll notice that it's showing image correctly.